# Angular Drag and Drop on Schema

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

In my Angular Application

I added a JSON element to a form on an Add click event.

Now I want to change add button to Drag and Drop feature.

Do we have any angular support to implement this .?[image]

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ng2-dragula. It is a nice package